# Having trouble with centering elements using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/dennismonsewicz/xRE83/1/

The headers (`h1, h2`) are centered in the div and I am simply just trying to horizontally center the three columns below the headers, but am having issues doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divs are floats and are causing it to not center as they float to the left.

Here's one way to do it:

HTML:

```
<div class="span10 clearfix">
```

CSS:

```
.span10 {margin:auto; width:500px; float:none;}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xRE83/7/